# How to solve UTF-8/Unicode problems in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I need a simple PHP & MySQL source that works fine on UTF8 Unicode system. Please give me the simplest source that works at 100% on UTF8 Unicode.

Comment: Think you could have gotten that from a fairly easy Google search

Answer (score 6):

Just tell both mysql and php that you using utf-8:

```
<?php
   mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

   $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password');
?>
```

Comment: Ok. I'll try. I set my db to UTF8 and UTF8_Unicode_ci

Comment: it inserts right chars into database, but in browser shows smth like that: "РљРѕРјРјРµРЅС‚РёСЂРѕРІР°С‚СЊ..." (cyrillic)

Comment: then tell the browser to use utf-8 to: `header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: <html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" />.....

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

Comment: cyrillic from HTML is rendering OK, but cyrillic that i read from database it's "РљРѕРјРјРµРЅС‚РёСЂРѕРІР°С‚СЊ..."

Comment: @puggan, i inserted  header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); before mysql connection, and now it reads perfectly from DB, but cyrillic that is wrote in html files is bullshit: "���������"

Comment: in your texteditor, click `save as` and see if its stored as UTF-8, (may be found other ways depending on editor)

Comment: @PugganSe, now it works well. The only problem is that i have this php error. Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at X:\home\spa\www\core\system.php:1) in X:\home\spa\www\core\config.php on line 30

Comment: forget about it. I fixed it. Thank you guys. Esspecialy Puggan Se.

Comment: @PugganSe, uppss. Another problem: in Google Chorme is allright, but in Mozilla it is not :(

Comment: Internet Explorer also works fine.